# How to pull up the inspector in A-Frame with JSBin on a mac

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

On the website, it mentions that you can pull up an inspector by pushing CTRL + ALT + i. I can't seem to get it to work on a mac. Is there another button combination.

Furthermore, I would like to be able to edit the scene in JSBin. However, pushing CTRL + ALT + i does not work. Here is my code to make a simple scene in JSBin.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, World! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, World! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.5.0/dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>

      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -1" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 1" rotation="0 45 0" width="1" height="1" depth="1"  color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 1" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
      <a-entity position="0 0 3.8">
        <a-camera></a-camera>
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I suspect it might have something to do with this line.

```
  <script src="https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.5.0/dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

At least on my Mac, it's Shift + CTRL + ALT + I. Tested in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

You can open it by going to your scene and pressing CTRL + Alt + i on Windows or CTRL + Option + i on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

See the [README](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe#basic-example) and [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/getting-started.html) for A-Frame URLs to use:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

But if it does work. ctrl/alt/i should work.

Else you can send a post message with `INJECT_AFRAME_INSPECTOR` to the I-Frame to open the Inspector (this is how aframe.io does it).